# jQuery - save checkboxes condition in cookie

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I have an array of checkboxes on the page and I want to save their condition in cookie. Have no idea how to make this... For example, I have HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="checkboxes[]">CB1<br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="checkboxes[]">CB1<br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="checkboxes[]">CB1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Incorporating three simple functions from [quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html), you can do this:

```
function createCookie(name,value,days) {
    if (days) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
        var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
    }
    else var expires = "";
    document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";
}

function readCookie(name) {
    var nameEQ = name + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
        if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
    }
    return null;
}

function eraseCookie(name) {
    createCookie(name,"",-1);
}

createCookie("checkboxes", $("input:checkbox").serialize(), 30);
alert(readCookie("checkboxes"));
```

[**You can try it here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/karim79/FK4p4/)

Comment: +1 for `.serialize()` -- a good function I often forget about in jQuery :)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at [this plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/Cookie). It allows you to read/write cookies using jQuery.

Comment: if you could provide a demo that would be more helpful

Answer (score 0):

Well in my eye I can see ways to archive you goal.

1. Use string with 0 and 1 (1 is checked and 0 not. The result is a string wich you can save in a cookie.
2. Use the json object to store it. Finally this will be also a string for saving it in the cookie.